# sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientBase._request' was never awaited

Tags: python, client, warnings, coroutine

I am trying to run python to print price of `BTCUSDT`.

the result was

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientBase._request' was never awaited.
```

this is the code:

```
import binance.client
from binance.client import Client
import My_API

client = Client(api_key=My_API.PKey, api_secret=My_API.Skey)
Price = client.get_average_price(Symbol = 'BTCUSDT')
print(Price)
```